# Retrieve data from object - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get all the category ids and and their names in magento. For that, In our template file I have added following code:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->getEntity();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($category);
echo '</pre>';
```

It returns following object.

```
 Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category Object
    (
        [_tree:protected] => 
        [_categoryProductTable:protected] => catalog_category_product
        [_isActiveAttributeId:protected] => 
        [_storeId:protected] => 
        [_attributes:protected] => Array
            (
                [42] => Array
                    (
                        [value_id] => 3
                        [entity_type_id] => 3
                        [attribute_id] => 42
                        [store_id] => 0
                        [entity_id] => 2
                        [value] => 1
                    )

                [67] => Array
                    (
                        [value_id] => 4
                        [entity_type_id] => 3
                        [attribute_id] => 67
                        [store_id] => 0
                        [entity_id] => 2
                        [value] => 1
                    )
               .................. going on ....
```

From this object shall I get attribute_id? If can kindly explain me.. And also explain what are the things present in the collection, if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you obtain this object?

Comment: I have used following code " $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->getEntity();"

Comment: You have to add this code to the question

Comment: In my magento template file

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try This:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
foreach ($category as $cat)
{
  $catObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getEntityId());

  //category Id
  var_dump($catObj->getEntityId());

  //category Name
  var_dump($catObj->getName());

}
```

Remember this loads all the categories (all categories created at the backend of any level and active/inactive).

you will need to filter as per your need. To do so you can filter at

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                      ->getCollection()
                      //ADD YOUR FILTERS HERE
                      /*LIKE THESE
                      ->addIsActiveFilter()
                      ->addLevelFilter(1) */
                      ;
```

Comment: It works. But may I know getEntityId means what in this snippet??

Comment: It's the category Id. The collection initially will NOT contain the category details so in order to get the category details like name , urlkey and other descriptions, we have to explicitly load the category using the Entity Id, which is the id of the category. then with the loaded category object we can access all info about the category. Hope I explained it.

Comment: Load function is only possible for get category fields like name, position, level etc.. Am I Right?

Comment: load can be used in case of id. if you need to get the category from other attributes such as name,sku,etc then you can use Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'category001'); you can replace sku with other attributes.

Comment: Which means no way to get like this $catObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('sku',$cat->getSku()); right??

Comment: No problem. Keep posting.